# background-color and rounded corner ie6 bug when print page

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-6

I want to  print HTML page with background colors and rounded corners  using internet explorer 6

Everything works fine before printing.  When I print the page background colors and rounded corners disappear

**CSS**

```
#div
{
       behavior: url(PIE.htc);            
       position:relative;
       background-color:silver;
       width:630px;
       margin:auto;
       border-radius:30px 0 0 30px;
       border:2px solid gray;
 }
```

Comment: You Use IE1. :D ....It will work perfectly. These days none uses IE6. Whoever using tell them to Update.

Comment: IE6 will no longer be supported in a month, to print background images / colours you need to turn it on in your browser options

Comment: Ok but my customer need application must run on ie6

Comment: Is your customer from Govt. Sector?

Comment: In Government sector only people use ie6 , p4 , Big Screen Monitor...Lol

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296326 (for printing) but you may want to point your client at this site: http://www.modern.ie/ie6countdown

Comment: Seriously: IE6 (and WinXP) will be declared officially end-of-life by Microsoft in April (just a few weeks away). After that date, **THERE WILL BE NO MORE SECURITY UPDATES FOR THEM. EVER.** It is almost certain that anyone still using them will be hacked in the next few months. You need to tell your customer to update urgently so they don't get hacked. And you personally need to stop supporting it so you don't have to run it, so that you don't get hacked. Personally, I would turn this project down unless they're paying you danger-money and willing to cover your costs if you do get hacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's intentional actually: since [1.0 beta 3](http://css3pie.com/2010/12/06/pie-1-0-beta-3-released/) and [this particular commit](https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/commit/828dac6129492722681b6dcd10f7e72426d1e392)...

> **Printing** – PIE now removes itself from all elements when the page is
>   printed. Besides avoiding many rendering problems, this also allows
>   the user’s printing preferences regarding backgrounds to be honored
>   and avoid wasting ink.

And it usually makes sense, ain't it? But yes, clients are different - and if they really really really want this feature, you'll have to either downgrade to PIE 1.0 beta 2 (the easiest way, but apparently riddled with downsides) - or build your custom version of `PIE.htc` that doesn't have `sources/OnPrint.js` included.